# bone heat weighting failed to find a solution for one or more bones

Tags: vertex-weights

i have seen this on here lots but i have followed your help and i'm still stuck, i'm really new to blender and unreal engine and just having problems all over he place but not being able to combine this is really frustrating. please help.

my file is at http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45450

i do hope someone can help.

thanking you in advance.

Comment: Automatic weights AFAIK will work best with quads (4 verts per face) or triangles (3).  Your mesh has some ridiculous ngons.  Might want to investigating remeshing of some sort.

Comment: thanks for that we looked back an an earlier save point in its development and it has lovely quads so thank you.